# How to write a dynamic tree

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, tree

## Description

There are trees with n nodes in total, and each node has a weight we may assume it's integer. And we have some operations on these trees:

1. Link(x, y) -- Link two nodes x and y, we can assume there is no edge between x and y before, and we can assume after add edge (x, y), the Graph still is a tree.
2. Cut(x, y) -- erase edge between x and y, we can assume there exists a edge between (x, y) before.
3. QueryMIN_Path(x, y) -- get the min weight in the path x->y, the input data Guarantee there is a path between x and y.
4. QueryMIN_Subtree(x) --get the min weight in x's subtree
5. Modify_Path(x, y, z) --add z to each node in path x -> y, the input data Guarantee there is a path between x and y.
6. Modify_Subtree(x, z) --add z to each node in subtree x
7. Change_root(x) --change the root of tree which contains x, and x become the root

we may assume all the operations are correct.

## Goal

I need all of these operations run in O(log(n)) per operation in amortized time.

Comment: @Turtle  It's not a homework, just a open discusstion.

Comment: @Turtle, I know several ways to do it, like Top Tree, but I want to know more

Comment: You can't add or remove an edge to a tree and still have a tree, so I think something must be missing in the description. Maybe you mean "forest" instead of "tree"?

Comment: @Anonymous yes , it's forest

Comment: You an read this paper "Dynamic Trees in Practice," by Tarjan and  Werneck. http://dx.doi.org/10.1145/1498698.1594231 They provide a comprehensive survey for all dynamic trees and experimental comparisons.

Comment: @Yu-HanLyu, very good material, you can post an answer.